# How to add more number of labels on x-axis using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axis

I have the following plot but I want to add additional labels on the `x axis`.

I've already tried `scale_x_continuous` but it doesn't work since my values are not numeric values, but dates.

how can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: "More x values", as in more date-time points? Can you also show the code you are using, with perhaps some example data?

Comment: Have you looked at `scale_x_date`? You can specify more breaks using the `breaks = ...` option

Comment: I think the problem is that R is not being able to notice that that column is in date format, even if I change to date manually during the import process.

When I view the document is changes to Unknown.

Comment: @Ana Raquel: Does the solution below work for your case?

Comment: Yes @Stan, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "more x values" you mean that you would like to have more labels on your x-axis, then you can adjust the frequency using the scale_x_dates argument like so:

```
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b-%y")
```

Here is my working example.  Please post your own if I misunderstood your question:

```
library("ggplot2")
# make the results reproducible
set.seed(5117)  

start_date <- as.Date("2015-01-01") 
end_date <- as.Date("2017-06-10")

# the by=7 makes it one observation per week (adjust as needed)
dates <- seq(from = start_date, to = end_date, by = 7)
val1 <- rnorm(length(dates), mean = 12.5, sd = 3)

qnt <- quantile(val1, c(.05, .25, .75, .95))

mock <- data.frame(myDate = dates, val1)

ggplot(data = mock, mapping = aes(x = myDate, y = val1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = qnt[1], colour = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = qnt[4], colour = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = qnt[2], colour = "lightgreen") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = qnt[3], colour = "lightgreen") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b-%y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]